# how use a Blob for send byte data?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, blob

I have encountered a problem using byte array. The exception it suggested to me that I ought to use Blob in the properties of HttpServletRequest , but I can not find information about this.

The complete package: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob

Can you say I like this class uses? or any web which has examples

Comment: Please describe what you want to accomplish from the beginning so we can help you better.

The blob class usage can be found in lots of places but its usage will differ depending on what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example of extracting blobs, I think here.
http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUpload
I'm not familiar with the datastore, but as far as I know, Blob types are 'just' wrappers for byte arrays.